# Android Studio on Ubuntu 18.04: No Fragments Found... How do I "create one or more Fragments in code"?

Tags: android-studio, android-fragments, ubuntu-18.04

## Scenario

I'm starting to learn Android Development on my Ubuntu laptop, but having issues with creating layouts with fragments.

## Steps Taken

1. I created a **new project** with an **Empty Activity**
2. I right-clicked my **app** folder and performed: **New > Fragment > Fragment (Blank)**,

   - Named it **TestingFragment**
   - Unchecked "**Include fragment factory methods?**"
   - Unchecked "**Include interface callbacks?**"
3. Under **res > layout** I updated the fragment (**fragment_testing**) to recognize it within the **main activity**
4. I went to the **activity_main.xml** file, added the **FrameLayout** to the layout
5. I tried to drag the **< fragment >** component to the **FrameLayout**
6. I receive an error message with just an **OK** button:

   No Fragments Found
   You must first create one or more Fragments in code.

## My Best Guess

It appears that my Android studio is not recognizing that I have the fragment code created and just need to add it to the layout.
Perhaps I need to configure the **Gradle** scripts to be able to find the **TestingFragment** class?

## What I've Tried from Googling Around

1. I have installed, uninstalled and re-installed Android Studio using [**Snapcraft**](https://snapcraft.io/android-studio)
2. I have installed, uninstalled and re-installed Android Studio using [**android-studio-ide-191.5791312-linux.tar.gz**](https://developer.android.com/studio#downloads) from the official Android Download site within the **/opt** directory.
3. I have made sure all **plugins** are checked via **File > Settings > Plugins**
4. I have verified that my **Android SDK Location** is pointing to the right folder via **Tools > SDK Manager**.
   Under **SDK Platforms** the following SDKs are installed and checked:

   - Android 10.0 (Q)
   - Android 7.1.1 (Nougat)
   - Android 7.0 (Nougat)
5. I have tried the **File > Invalidate Caches / Restart...** option choosing the **Invalidate and Restart** button
6. I have tried the **File > Sync Project with Gradle Files** option.
7. I have tried the **File > Sync with File System** option

**Edit:**
I have been able to go into the xml of the **main_activity** layout file and add a fragment tag manually and found that it can work. The following is the manual tag I managed to add:

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment"
        android:name="android.example.testfragments.ListFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_list" />
```

Still working on fixing the drag-drop "**No fragments found**" issue.

## Where to go from here?

Does anyone know where I can go from here other than virtualizing another OS like Windows to see if it works there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution

So after hours of poking around the settings and googling around, I discovered the reason why it wasn't working by accident.

While creating a new project, the application's **Package name** field **cannot** follow the "**android.example.packageName**" pattern.

After being unsuccessful for so long, I decided to try a  new project and change all the options to completely start anew from scratch. During the process, I changed the package name to "**com.frags.testing**".

I then proceeded with the steps described above to make a fragment and I was successfully able to add the fragment using the drag-drop method into the **main_activity** layout.

I also verified that this worked by going back to my previous project where it wasn't working and creating a **new package** named **fragments** and refactored the fragment class to that new package. I then went back to the **main_activity** layout and dragged the **< fragment >** component to the layout and it successfully found the fragment.

Hope this helps someone else out there.

Cheers,

Justin